# Error Not found by using SimpleModal Login

Tags: wordpress, authentication, simplemodal

I'm using [SimpleModal Login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simplemodal-login/) (wordpress plugin).

This plugin shows *register* and *login* in modal, and has custom urls for these options.

Login url :

```
<a href="/wp-login.php?redirect_to=<?php echo esc_url_raw($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>" class="simplemodal-login" rel="nofollow">Log In</a>
```

After login, this code refers you to page/post that you were on before login. On english url for post/page it was right, but my language is persian and i have problem with login.

When I login to current post like:

```
http://localhost/wp/بازی/
```

the url changes to :

```
http://localhost/wp/Ø¨Ø§Ø²Û%C2%8C/
```

[screenshot from url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbeQO.jpg)

and page not found, but login works and I can see my user menu.

I need to be on current post/page after login (more detail: I use osx theme of simplemodal login).

Answer (score 0):

i found answer :

use :

```
<?php wp_loginout($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>
```

instead of :

```
<a href="/wp-login.php?redirect_to=<?php echo esc_url_raw($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>" class="simplemodal-login" rel="nofollow">Log In</a>
```

and it does work correctly :)